# OSM tile server "renderd" keeps using wrong user

Tags: openstreetmap, rendering

I set up my machine to serve tiles following instructions on https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-20-04-osm.

I am currently on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

I imported the data into the database, created system user *osm* and database user *osm*. Running renderd in foreground seems to work (tiles are rendered), but fails when run as daemon. This is likely because the process (?) is alwas run as user **_renderd** (which I did not create). Of course this user has no database permissions whatsoever, which then causes the daemon to crash.

In */etc/init.d/renderd* I specified the following:

```
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Mapnik rendering daemon"
NAME=renderd
DAEMON=/usr/bin/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS="-c /etc/renderd.conf"
PIDSOCKDIR=/run/$NAME
PIDFILE=$PIDSOCKDIR/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
RUNASUSER=osm
```

For completness here's the content of */etc/renderd.conf*

```
; BASIC AND SIMPLE CONFIGURATION:
[renderd]
stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
num_threads=4
tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile

[mapnik]
plugins_dir=/usr/lib/mapnik/3.1/input
font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/truetype
font_dir_recurse=true

[default]
URI=/osm/
XML=/home/osm/openstreetmap-carto/style.xml
HOST=localhost
TILEDIR=/var/lib/mod_tile
TILESIZE=256
```

So is specified "RUNASUSER" to use the correct user, but this seems not to be respected.

Where does the user "_renderd" come from and why is it used? More importantly what can I do to prevent this behaviour and force using user "osm"?

Comment: Slight aside point, but have you tried using a docker image with everything built and ready to go for serving tiles from OSM? e.g. https://awesome-dev.com/dev-solution/offline-tile-server-with-openstreetmap-docker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/renderd.service
```

and specify the user there as well

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/renderd -f
User=osm
```

I don't know if both changes are strictly necessary, but I found this is what changed the user it ran under. The renderd package from osmadmins created that file, and created the *_renderd* user. Don't forget to change the ownership of certain directories as those instructions specify, or renderd will fail with permission problems once it is running as *osm*.

There are other instructions for Debian that simply use *_renderd* for the database user, avoiding this complication:

https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-debian-11/

Comment: Forgot to answer this question myself. You're right, that change fixed the problem for me, too.